# Unable to upgrade Cinnamon with Linux Mint 13

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, cinnamon

I would like to upgrade to the latest version of Cinnamon. I'm running Linux Mint 13 in a virtual machine. Everywhere I look, I see the same instructions:

```
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gwendal-lebihan-dev/cinnamon-stable 
> sudo apt-get update 
> sudo apt-get install cinnamon
```

When I do that, apt-get install reports that "cinnamon is already the newest version". When I check the version with "cinnamon --version", it reports 1.4 and not version 1.6 (or later) like I expect. Is there something else I need to do?

Comment: You need to enable the romeo repo for unstable packages on 13 apparently; see http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=208&t=117664

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't enable the romeo repo, but instead followed the instructions in this link from the forums jasonwryan pointed me to:  http://blog.linuxmint.com/?p=2225

For reference, the instructions are:

```
1. Open the “Software Sources” tool from “Menu -> Preferences -> Software Sources”
2. Click on the “Backported packages (backports)” checkbox
3. Launch the “Update Manager” from “Menu->Administration->Update Manager”
4. Select all level 1 and level 2 updates
5. Click on “Install Updates”
```

I now have Cinnamon 1.6.7 installed on Mint 13.